# Generating an image and then displaying it on flask

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, web, flask

I am new to Flask framework and I am trying to dispaly a few images like wordcloud, graphs and piecharts generated in the program on flask. I'm trying to store the images generated in `image` list and then return it. Then use that in the HTML file to display each image. Over here I am just entering the wordcloud generation section and the `app.route` part.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import base64
images = []
def analyse(df)
    # genrate a word cloud image
    wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='white',
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40,
        scale=3,
        random_state=42
    ).generate(str(df["Review"]))

    figfile3 = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(figfile3, format='png')
    figfile3.seek(0)  # rewind to beginning of file
    wordcloudimg = base64.b64encode(figfile3.getvalue())
    images.append(wordcloudimg)
    return images
```

`df["Review"]` has textual reviews.

```
@app.route('/')
def finaldef():
    images = analyse(df)
    return render_template('pages.html', image=images)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

A section of the pages HTML file is

```
{% block head %}
<title>Pages</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Images</h1>
    {% for i in image %}
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ i }}" width="500">
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The output comes as image symbols but not the wordcloud that I had generated.
I would really appreciate the help.
Thank You

Comment: Not sure if the spaces in `<img src="...{{ i }}"` might be upsetting the browser. Try going into your browser's `Developer/Debug` mode and checking the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess, as I haven't been able to test with the word cloud library.

`base64.b64encode` returns an object of type `bytes`.

The fix might simply be to decode the return value of this, so you get type `str`.  Modify your code to do this:

```
    wordcloudimg = base64.b64encode(figfile3.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly with a matplot bar-graph but not with wordcloud or with matplot piechart